# Safari Extension Invalid Code Signature Identifier

Tags: xcode, safari-extension

Facts:

- I am trying to upload an app to the app store.
- I am deploying via xcode archive distribution
- I have setup an app appstoreconnect.apple.com
- I have setup an ID on developer.apple.com

When I try to deploy and it getting signed I get this error

```
App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-90334: “Invalid Code Signature Identifier. The identifier “my_app_id-55554333a757b7473a4b4s7f65bd545a78w88836” in your code signature for “My App Name” must match its Bundle Identifier “my_app_id”
```

55554333a757b7473a4b4s7f65bd545a78w88836 is just an example of what it looks like.  I have changed the real value because I'm not sure what it is

I have no idea where this number is coming from.  I have searched my xcode for it, nothing.

I declare my Bundle Identifier I very explicitly just just `my_app_id`. Why is this number being appended to the bundle id?

Help?

Answer (score 2):

Try once with auto signing instead of manual signing.

Answer (score 0):

try
set Bundle Identifier has 
com.example.yourapp